# Как сохранить запись в бд, если поле Entity является объектом?

Tags: java, spring, freemaker

У меня есть 2 таблицы и сущности к ним:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "user_phone")
    public String phone;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_role")
    public Role role;

    ...
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users_roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    public int id;

    @Column(name = "role_name")
    public String name;

    @Column(name = "role_value")
    public String value;

    ...
}
```

Сеттеры и геттеры опустил.

Также есть контроллер, который сохраняет пользователя:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/users/create")
public class Create extends Base {
    private final String template = "users/create";

    @Autowired
    private RegValid regValid;

    @GetMapping
    public String get(User user) {
        return getTemplate();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String post(User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        regValid.validate(user, bindingResult);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return getTemplate();
        }

        userService.save(user);
        model.addAttribute("save", true);

        return "users/index";
    }
}
```

И в шаблоне:

```
<@spring.bind "user.role"/>
<#list spring.status.errorMessages as error>
    <span class="error">${error}</span>
</#list>

    <select name="${spring.status.expression}" class="form-control">
        <#list roles as role>
            <option value="${role.getId()}" <#if spring.status.value?? && role.equals(spring.status.value)>selected</#if>>${role.getName()}</option>
        </#list>
    </select>

</label>
```

<s>Какого хрена</s> Почему:

1. не работает без `User.serialVersionUID`;
2. При сохранении вылезает ошибка о несовпадении типов:

> Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required
>   type beans.Role for property role; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
>   [@javax.persistence.OneToOne @javax.persistence.JoinColumn beans.Role]
>   for value 99; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Provided
>   id of the wrong type for class beans.Role. Expected: class
>   java.lang.Integer, got class java.lang.Long; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the wrong type for
>   class beans.Role. Expected: class java.lang.Integer, got class
>   java.lang.Long

Comment: `не работает без User.serialVersionUID;` имеется ввиду, что вываливается чушь вида `Failed to convert from type [byte[]] to type [java.lang.Object] for value '{-84, -19, 0, 5, 115`

Comment: Так, со второй проблемой разобрался заменив `Role.id` на `long` o_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**serialVersionUID** - штука, которая нужна для сериализации.
Грубо говоря это своего рода система контроля версий класса. Допустим вы написали класс, в нем 10 полей. Этот класс сериализируется. Но через какое -то время вы удалили одно поле и теперь сериализованные объекты старого класса не имеют возможности корректно десириализоваться, ведь все необходимые поля в классе отсутсвуют.

Изменения **serialVersionUID**  говорит системе о том, что класс изменился. И тогда при попытке десириализации объектов с другим **serialVersionUID** вы получаете исключение.

Весь фокус в том, что если вы явно не прописываете **serialVersionUID**, то его генерит сама система, вроде как конструктор по умолчанию,  по сути значение этого числа не важно, важно его изменение. Поэтому поставить можете любую цифру, все будет ок. Мало того, делать это настоятельно рекомендуется, потому как по идее в неизменяющемся классе **serialVersionUID** системой должен генерироваться одинаковый, но в реальной жизни это далеко не всегда правда.

Посему, не прописывая **serialVersionUID**, вы рискуете получить серьезные проблемы с сериализацией. И именно это и происходит в вашем случае.

Comment: Дмитрий, у вас хорошие ответы, но вы пишите их простыней, её сложно читать. Делайте небольшие отступы, чтобы глазу было за что зацепиться.

Comment: Так, хорошо. Но у меня ведь объект сериализуется по сути в запись в БД. Как могут не совпадать версии объектов этого класса, если в БД нет никаких записей о версии, да и данные там хранятся совсем по другому.

Comment: Понял проблему. Ошибка возникала, когда в сессии один объект, изменяется класс (например тип какого-то поля) и соответственно поле из сессии уже не могёт в поле класса.