# Добрый день,я начинающий изучать java,нужна ваша помощь)

Tags: java

Решаю задачу :
Имеется корневая папка. В этой папке могут находиться текстовые файлы, а также другие папки. В других папках также могут находится текстовые файлы и папки (уровень вложенности может оказаться любым).
Написать на java программу, которая находит все текстовые файлы, отсортировать их по имени и склеить содержимое в один текстовый файл.

Написал класс для поиска текстовых файлов

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Main1 {
  private static ArrayList<File>listWithFileNames = new ArrayList<>();
  public static int content;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    getListFiles("C:\\backet");
    for (File fil: listWithFileNames) {
      String res = fil.getName();
      if (res.contains(".txt")) {
        try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(fil)) {
          // читаем посимвольно
          while ((content = reader.read()) != -1) {
            //System.out.print((char)content);
          }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
          System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        // System.out.println(fil.getName());
      }
    }
    //Записываем в файл
    try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\backet\\global.txt", false)) {
      writer.write((char) content);
      // запись по символам
      writer.append('\n');
      writer.append('E');

      writer.flush();
      writer.close();
      System.out.println("Запись прошла успешно");
    } catch (IOException ex) {

      System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }
  public static void getListFiles(String str) {
    File f = new File(str);
    for (File s: f.listFiles()) {
      if (s.isFile()) {
        listWithFileNames.add(s);
      } else if (s.isDirectory()) {
        getListFiles(s.getAbsolutePath());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Не работает запись в файл

Не пойму как отсортировать `ArrayList<File> listWithFileNames`
И дальше завис,прошу помощи,подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать
И если можете подскажите как оформить код чтобы выглядел достойно
Спасибо)))

Comment: Тут вам нужна рекурсия. Пишите метод, итерирующий по текущему каталогу. Все текстовые файлы складываете в лист, а для каталогов рекурсивно вызываете этот же метод. После нахождения всех необходимых файлов в простом цикле сливаете их в один.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте что-то вроде этого...
Для сортировки используется класс-компаратор. Он добавлен ниже. В нем можно описать любую логику сортировки элементов коллекции на ваше усмотрение.
Кроме того, старайтесь писать простые короткие методы. Их легко читать и достаточно легко отладить работу.
А еще Java 8 дает возможность использовать лямбды и стримы. В некоторых случаях это облегчает жизнь. Например, с помощью функционального интерфейса FilenameFilter очень легко создать фильтр для файлов.
Я использую рекурсивный обход папок, полагаю, что для данной задачи он оптимален. Вы можете решить задачу без рекурсии, но метод в любом случае станет сложнее.

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      String directoryName = "C:\\backet";
      String resultFileName = "C:\\backet\\global.txt";

      FilenameFilter txtFilter = (File dir, String name) -> {
          return (new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+name).isDirectory()) || name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
      };

      List<File> textFileNameList = getFileName(new File(directoryName), new ArrayList<>(), txtFilter);
      Collections.sort(textFileNameList, new SortFileName());
      String resultText = fileWriter(textFileNameList, Charset.forName("cp1251")); //may be "UTF-8" or else
      fileWriter(resultFileName, resultText);

  }

    public static List<File> getFileName(File directory, List<File> fileNameList, FilenameFilter txtFilter) {
        for (File file : directory.listFiles(txtFilter)) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) getFileName(file, fileNameList, txtFilter);
            else fileNameList.add(file);
        }
        return fileNameList;
    }

    public static String fileWriter(List<File> textFileNameList, Charset charset) {
        final StringBuilder allText = new StringBuilder();
        textFileNameList.forEach((file) -> {
            try {
                Files.lines(Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()), charset).
                        forEach((t) -> {allText.append(t).append("\r\n");});
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Main1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        });
        return allText.toString();
    }

    public static boolean fileWriter(String fileName, String text) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedOutputStream bof = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName))) {
            bof.write(text.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}

class SortFileName implements Serializable, Comparator<File>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5657490615422814108L;

    @Override
    public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
        return file1.getName().compareTo(file2.getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое,а для чего вы в методе сортировки присваиваете переменной значение serialVersionUID = -5657490615422814108L?

Comment: Я уже писал про serialVersionUID здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777744/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b4-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-entity-%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc/777829#777829

Comment: Прочел,теперь понятно,спасибо